# Replace Flex preloader bar with an indeterminate spinner?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I have a AS spinner class that I downloaded from Jake Hawkes ([click here to see it running](http://grakl.com/flex/SpinnerApp/SpinnerApp.html)).

I want to replace the flex application preloader with this spinner. I have previously used custom preloaders, but that was just for editing what already existed. Anyone know how that spinner.as could be used instead of the loading bar?

**EDIT**
This is the extremely cool custom preloader that Im going to try to edit (it extends Sprite) view source enabled: 
http://blogagic.com/14/the-blogagic-custom-flex-preloader

Brian

Comment: The spinner I was trying to use extends UIComponent, and I have since heard that UIComponent cannot be used in the preloader. Will have another try with a pure actionscript component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little late but I just came across this site. The spinner here seamed pretty well developed and documented.

http://flexdevtips.blogspot.com/2011/05/simple-animating-preloader-and.html

Comment: I may need to use this now pretty soon, and that example is for Flex 4, perfect!

Answer (score 1):

WindowedApplication has `preloader` property, which you can set class of your preloader. This class should implement IPreloaderDisplay. Google has answers for this in top results: http://askmeflash.com/article/7/custom-preloader-progress-bar-flex.

Comment: Yeah, ive seen that link. Didnt post the question without first trying to do it myself. That example edits the loading bar alright, but Im trying to replace the loading bar with a spinner.